# Is there a quick way to use chef cookbooks on github?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-solo, berkshelf

Is there a quick way to use chef cookbooks on github?
I'm trying: `chef-solo -r https://github.com/phlipper/chef-htop/archive/master.tar.gz -o htop` but I'm getting a ruby error.
Is doing what I want to do possible?

Edit: Quickest way I've found is:

```
cd /tmp 
wget https://github.com/phlipper/chef-htop/archive/master.tar.gz
tar xzvf master.tar.gz 
mkdir -p /var/chef/cookbooks
cd chef-htop-master
berks vendor /var/chef/cookbooks
chef-solo -o htop
```

I feel like the use of Berkshelf is an issue here.

Edit: To clarify my goal, I'd like to be able to leverage `chef` and the community when I want to install software on a platform I am not familiar with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fast way would be to use Berkshelf and then `berks vendor`. In days long past you could use archives like that, but I think it was only zip files and I'm pretty sure most of that support was removed, and it wouldn't have worked with the layout from GitHub archive downloads to start with.

Create a new `Berksfile` with content like:

```
source 'https://supermarket.chef.io/'
cookbook 'htop'
```

And then run `berks install && berks vendor cookbooks/`. This will create a solo-compatible cookbooks folder. You'll still need to fill in the node JSON and `solo.rb` config though.

Comment: ok thanks. I was hoping for something a tad faster. I could probably automate this workflow fairly easily.

Comment: Also, in Berkshelf, you can specify a git source for a cookbook, which might work for the OP: `cookbook 'application', git: 'git@github.com:company-cookbook/application.git'`. It's not pointing to the downloadable archive, but it has the same effect.